# Remesh-Modifier in Sharp mode generates overlapping faces?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I found out that it's better that a mesh consists of quads than triangles (http://blog.digitaltutors.com/modeling-with-quads-or-triangles/). So I thought I will give it a try and use the remesh-modifier to make quads.

I created a **icosphere** and added the remesh-modifier (see screenshot). You can see some holes which in fact are overlapping faces. That's more or less ugly and I don't want that. I know I could delete the overlapping faces and create new correct faces, but I am writing a procedural mesh add-on and so the way of doing it manually is out of the scope.

[image]
When I am using Mode: Smooth the holes/overlapping faces disappear but I am not so sure if they could come back again.

Could someone explain to me why this is happeing?
The Smooth-Mode is working without sharp-feature detection. But what is a "sharp-feature" on a icosphere? And why is it a problem for the modifier?

Thanks!

Comment: I am writing a procedural mesh generator for a low poly game. The art style of the mesh will be defined over the mesh topology. A low poly mesh built out of triangles will look different than quads. I don't know why the base mesh depends. I thought the remesh modifier doesn't destroy the mesh but it rebuilds it. Additionally, the quad only mesh could help me creating seams automatically for uv mapping.

Comment: Try turning down the amount of sharpness. AFAIK the sharpness feature is more of a post-processing feature which deforms vertices close to sharp parts in an attempt to match the shape of the base mesh. With sharpness set to 1 this often results in rather extreme deformations of single vertices. That said, tris aren't inherently evil. There are some cases where they may be preferable or even desired, e.g. for an artistic "low poly" style.

Comment: There are still overlapping faces when sharpness is set to zero.

Comment: Hm.. Not for me?

Comment: Look here: http://oi61.tinypic.com/r7lsea.jpg